# How does the YouTube 2014 voting system work?

Tags: comments, voting, community, social-interfaces

As of this post, YouTube users on the site to upvote/downvote comments below videos. What confuses me is that the # of upvotes are visible while downvotes aren't ever visible. What advantage does it have for users to view comments that aren't necessarily helpful within the conversation if you're hiding the downvotes. Additionally does YouTube have any sort of press release or post on how this voting system works?

**Example Below:**

[image]

Comment: It might be the net score, just just upvotes?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that they're attempting to prevent "downvote train", e.g. users think it's good, cool and okay to downvote an unnecessarily heavily downvoted post, assuming the downvote indicator is visible, due to maturity of typical YouTube user.

I don't think we'll gain anything if downvote indicator becomes visible, so it's better to leave it hidden as a solution.

Please note that this is just my thoughts. And as second thought, YouTube is pretty bad at those kind of stuff so it was probably done without good reason.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to support these assertions? At the moment, they read as opinions.

Comment: @3nafish Did you even read, didn't you? I said it was just my thoughts. There is no evidence, because YouTube didn't give any. Also this thread is several months old.

Comment: I read it.  Stating that your answer is only an opinion doesn't make it any less of an opinion or any more suitable for the site.  If you can find no evidence, it's better not to answer. From the [Help Center](http://ux.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer): "avoid trying to answer questions which...solicit opinions rather than facts."  If you can *find* evidence, it's not too late to improve your post.

Comment: @3nafish In my opinion that the majority of comments in UX User Experience Stack Exchange are mainly opinions due to lack of evidence supplement for user experience related area because most companies who do research keep the information confidential. Nobody can answer OP's question because none of us have evidence since YouTube did not supply one. Let's take one of [my comment](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/52678/change-text-on-disabled-menu-entries/52679#52679) in an example, it's 100% opinion and I believe it's correct, so do others. I cannot supply evidence because there is no way.

Comment: The question is unnecessarily specific (limited to YouTube), but a good answer would not need to be (addressing the representation of counts in a social voting system more generally). I would be surprised if there have been no studies published considering graphic representations of voting systems, perhaps including such metrics as their impact upon the number or length of comments submitted and/or read.  Even if no such studies exist, it's better to leave the question unanswered than to respond with unsubstantiated speculation.

Comment: Ours is a field that requires great rigor if we are to earn the respect of the developers we work with.  I downvote opinion-based answers in order to stand for the professional integrity of a fact-driven UX practice.  If we just make stuff up and don't take our research seriously, how can we expect developers to take us seriously?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for not display the down votes is to encourage user to comment to participate.  If you made a comment and you see a lot of down votes, you are unlikely to comment again, you get discouraged.  By hiding the down vote count, users can down vote and commentators can make comments.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to support this assertion? At the moment, it reads as just opinion.

Answer (score -1):

Because Google doesnt want to have negativity on the site. There are no bad comments, just good and neutral comments. They don't want people to get upset because they get a lot of downvotes, so they just hide it all. The same goes for the video rating system. Upvotes are displayed as a bright blue bar, while the downvotes are displayed as a hard to notice light grey bar.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to support this assertion?  At the moment, it reads as just opinion.

Comment: Kudos, you are very good at reading. Ofcourse its entirely speculative. I thought that was the point of this site. At least, thats what the other answers seem to imply.

Comment: That's true, they don't want people to express negative emotions and associate their website with them. This rule doesn't apply to Google only. That's why, e.g., there's also no "disliking" on Facebook &c.